# How to get coords of map / image map

Tags: imagemap, coords

I am looking for a method (programmatic) or software that can get coords of image or map, like us states or Germany province regarding on state border (edges). 
It will be exists this feature for known countries, but I need for others, where I will upload image or iterate it and get coords of area for html image map.
any help please

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for the same thing, and I found this while googling around

it should help

http://www.sbrady.com/hotsource/html/imgmaps.html